# MODX revo работа с ClientConfig+miniShop2

Tags: modx, minishop2, cart

**Всем привет! Имеется корзина на сайте. Нужно, что бы с админки через ClientConfig можно было управлять показом блока корзины.
Сама корзина выведена через chunk в header
Все действия по скрытию провожу в header-е
Пробовал через phx**

```
[[ [[++disable_text]]
:is=`2022-04-17`
:then=`[[!msMiniCart? &tpl=`cart_mini`]]`:
else=`Магазин закрыт`]]
```

**Так же пробовал через модуль IF**

```
[[If? $[[++disable_text]]
   &subject=`2022-04-17`
   &operator=`==`
   &then=`[[!msMiniCart? &tpl=`cart_mini`]]`
   &else=`Магазин закрыт`
]]
```

**В идеале хочу сделать так, что бы в админке я выставлял промежуток времени в который корзина недоступна, и соответственно она доступна**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Я новичок**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Синтаксис похоже неверный. Что если так:

```
[[++disable_text:is=`2022-04-17`:then=`[[!msMiniCart? &tpl=`cart_mini`]]`:else=`Магазин закрыт`]]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, все получилось!

Comment: отлично, отметьте ответ как решение.